# Spring to inject DBCollection instance

Tags: spring, mongodb, dependency-injection

To get the employees collection in my j2ee app I use:

```
DBCollection employees= mongoTemplate.getCollection("employees");
```

I would like to avoid making the same call all over in the code,

I have the mongo template injected as:

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate  mongoTemplate;
```

Is it possible to make "employees" bean in spring and inject it to my controller?

How to make sure mongoTemplate initialization takes place first

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to prepare such beans. Just transfer the collection name to **mongoTemplate** directly or indirectly when invoking.
This is one method of **mongoTemplate**:

```
public <T> List<T> find(final Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName)
```

Comment: What if there is additional collections I use?